UpsertEntityAsync throwing error after i migrate from Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to Azure.Data.Tables
i am in progress of migrating an existing project that have Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to Azure.Data.Tables. I was following the migration guide and implemented my custom model with  ITableEntity
with cosmos the insert looked like
private async Task InsertOrMergeAsync(CloudTable table, OfficeSupplyEntity record)
{
    var insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(record);
    await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOp);
}

after migration it converted to
    private async Task InsertOrMergeAsync(TableClient table, OfficeSupplyEntity record)
    {
        await table.UpsertEntityAsync(record);
    }

but now I get an error
An error occurred while processing this request.
RequestId:915023cb-f88d-47c3-81f0-1debbf39c8ef
Time:2024-12-19T07:26:55.088Z
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: InvalidInput

Content:
{"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request.\nRequestId:915023cb-f88d-47c3-81f0-1debbf39c8ef\nTime:2024-12-19T07:26:55.088Z"}}}

Headers:
Server: Azurite-Table/3.33.0
x-ms-error-code: REDACTED
x-ms-request-id: 915023cb-f88d-47c3-81f0-1debbf39c8ef
x-ms-version: REDACTED
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2024 07:26:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: REDACTED
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8

in the guide also it is unclear in this section
directly quoting below
Previously in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table, we would create a TableOperation and execute it with the table client.
The result of the operation must be casted back to the entity type.
// Create the InsertOrReplace table operation
TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);

// Execute the operation.
TableResult result = cloudTable.Execute(insertOrMergeOperation);

// Cast the result.
OfficeSupplyOld insertedCustomer = result.Result as OfficeSupplyOld;

Now in Azure.Data.Tables, using the TableClient, we can simply pass our entity to the UpsertEntity method which will create or update the entity depending on whether
or not it already exists.
// Upsert the newly created entity.
tableClient.UpsertEntity(tableEntity);

in the guide what is tableEntity? is it different from entity?

As the error shoes Invalid input Check whether all the provided inputs are valid and are in correct format or not.

Did you face any error while inserting data into the Azure Cosmos Table?

hi thanks for reply. with Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table i dont get any errors but for the same model it gives this error with Azure.Data.Tables. from provided inputs are valid, can i know what will make some fields invalid?

@Balaji btw my models have more fields than this like https://codeshare.io/64oXOo , when i was using cosmos package. most of the time my array fields may become empty, is that a problem too

Once try with this Connection string format DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storageName>;AccountKey=<primaryKey>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net

@Balaji i tried by manually creating a TableEntity var entity = new TableEntity(record.PartitionKey, record.RowKey)  {      { "Field1", record.Field1},.... and then inserted. Noticed that i get the same error when i set the fields having array values. is this correct? After removign array fields and the enum field it inserted. A column was not created if a field has  a null value. With the older cosmos package i didnt have this problem

hmm i dont think connection string is the issue

Azure Data Tables don't support storing arrays. Try by converting Array to String. You can serialize the array into a string and store it as a single property. When reading the entity, you can deserialize the string back into an array.


UpsertEntityAsync throwing error after i migrate from Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table to Azure.Data.Tables

tableEntity and entity are different, where tableEntity is a flexible container for the properties of an entity in Azure Table Storage and entity is a variable used in code to represent an instance of a table entity.
As the Azure Data Table doesn't support storing arrays it throws an error. Try with the below code for storing arrays in Azure Data Table. It Converts the array into a JSON string using a serializer JsonSerializer.Serialize, this allows the array to be stored as a single property in Azure Table Storage. Now deserialize using JsonSerializer.Deserialize so the JSON string is deserialized into an array.
class TableStorageArray
{
    private const string storageAccountName = "<accName>";  
    private const string storageAccountKey = "<primaryKey>";  
    private const string tableName = "TableB";

    private async Task InsertOrMergeAsync(TableClient tableClient, Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity record)
    {
        await tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(record, TableUpdateMode.Merge);
    }

    private async Task InsertOrMergeAsync(CosmosTable.CloudTable table, CosmosTable.DynamicTableEntity record)
    {
        var operation = CosmosTable.TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(record);
        await table.ExecuteAsync(operation);
    }

    private async Task StorageAsync()
    {
        string connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storageAccountName};AccountKey={storageAccountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        var tableClient = new TableServiceClient(connectionString).GetTableClient(tableName);
        await tableClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var storageAccount = CosmosTable.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var table = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName);
        await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Table connected or created.");

        var partitionKey = "1";
        var rowKey = "1";
        var arrayField = new[] { "Value1", "Value6", "Value9" };
        var arrayAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(arrayField);

        var recordForTableClient = new Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey)
        {
            { "Name", "Sai Paul" },
            { "ArrayField", arrayAsJson }
        };

        var recordForCloudTable = new CosmosTable.DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey)
        {
            Properties = {
                { "Name", new CosmosTable.EntityProperty("Sai Paul") },
                { "ArrayField", new CosmosTable.EntityProperty(arrayAsJson) }
            }
        };

        await InsertOrMergeAsync(tableClient, recordForTableClient);

        await InsertOrMergeAsync(table, recordForCloudTable);

        var retrievedEntity = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        string retrievedJson = retrievedEntity.Value.GetString("ArrayField");
        var deserializedArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(retrievedJson);

        Console.WriteLine("Deserialized Array:");
        foreach (var item in deserializedArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var example = new TableStorageArray();
            await example.StorageAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Output:
Table connected or created.
Deserialized Array:
Value1
Value6
Value9


i tried by removing the array fields from the entity model (not tableEntity) then UpsertEntity worked with entity as well. maybe because both imlement ITableEntity
